# put text to photos like instanote android app

Tags: java, android, layout, github

I want to make edit text which will work like [instanote app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instanote.pro) in that you can move text you can adjust size. It will be automatically adjusted when you increase or decrease edit text's size, when you move the text it also be adjustable. Any body know if there is an source code please tell me i have tried github, code.google.com but could not searched out but could not find out?

I think they have make it custome by doing

```
       public class BaseEditText extends EditText
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample code snippet, hope its a good start for you,

public class EditTextClass extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

```
private EditText txt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txt = (EditText) findViewById(YourEditTextId);
    txt.setOnTouchListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   if(event.getX() >= txt.getWidth() - 5 && event.getX() <= txt.getWidth()
        event.getY() >= txt.getHeight() - 5 && event.getY() <= txt.getHeight()) {
       txt.setWidth(event.getX()); 
       txt.setHeight(event.getY());
   }
   return true;
}
```

}